# Confusion on Ring of continuous functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $C$ be the ring of continuous functions $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with addition and multiplication defined pointwise. Let $I=\{f \in C:f(0)=f(1)=0\}$. Then $I$ is an ideal. I know that $C/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, if we define a homomorphism map $\phi: C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\phi(f)= (f(0),f(1))$ and use the first isomorphism theorem.

But if we define another map $\psi: C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $\psi(f)= f(0)+f(1)$, then we can again use the first isomorphism theorem to show $C/I \cong \mathbb{R}$. But now we have $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, which is not true.

I think there's something going wrong with the map $\psi$ not being injective or surjective, but I can't find where the problem is.

Please let me know where went wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: The kernel of $\psi$ is not $I.$ It is strictly bigger. $C/\ker\psi\cong\Bbb R^2/(\Bbb R(1,-1)).$

Comment: To see that the kernel of $\psi$ is not $I$, consider the function $f(x)=\cos(\pi x)$. Then $f\notin I$, since $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=-1$, but $f(0)+f(1)=0$. The map *is* surjective, since the real $r$ can be obtained as the image of the constant function $f(x)=\frac{r}{2}$.